# How do case-insensitive filesystems display both upper and lower case file names?

Tags: filesystems, filenames, case-sensitivity

This question occurred to me the other day when I was working on a development project that relies on an opinionated framework with regard to file names. The framework (irrelevant here) wanted to see upper-case-first filenames. This got me thinking.

On a case-insensitive file system, say extFAT or HFS+ (specifically non-case sensitive) how does the file system provide access to the same file with **both** upper and lower case versions of the filename.

For example:

```
$ cd ~/Documents
$ pwd
/home/derp/Documents

$ cd ../documents
$ pwd
/home/derp/documents

$ cd ../docuMents
$ pwd
/home/derp/docuMents

$ cd ../DOCUMENTS
$ pwd
/home/derp/DOCUMENTS

$ cd ../documentS
$ pwd
/home/derp/documentS
```

All of these commands will resolve to the same directory. Is this behavior, specifically the output from `pwd`just a function of `bash` in this case just showing me what it thinks I want to see?

Another example:

```
$ ls ~/Documents
Derp.txt    another.txt    whatThe.WORLD
```

The filesystem here reports the case of the original filename as created by the user or program.

At what point in the filesystem stack is the human readable filename preserved as it was created (eg. upper and lower case) so that it can be accessed by any combination of the correct upper and lowercase ASCII characters? Is this just a regex trick somewhere or is there something else going on?

EDIT:
It looks like the behavior I am curious about is found in **case-preserving** case-insensitive filesystems after some more research...

Comment: Not writing this as an answer because I don't know for sure any more but I believe that you can not have ~/Documents and ~/documents in that file system. But when you cd ~/Documents or ~/documents your going the same place and your shell is "playing nice" by remembering what you typed. The other side is that some FS store the way it was created in an aux. chunk of data. For example storing ~/Documents in a lookup table but writing to the FS as ~/documents. Basically creating an illusion that the file system cares about casing when it doesn't.

Comment: From what I've observed, in the event that a directory contains two file names which are identical except for case, non-case-sensitive file systems may respond to a request for a given file by arbitrarily selecting one.  Such situations can arise if the rules for upper/lowercase conversion change after a file gets created.

Comment: Cool information about NTFS's case preserving nature: http://superuser.com/questions/364057/why-is-ntfs-case-sensitive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A case-insensitive filesystem just means that whenever the filesystem has to ask "does A refer to the same file/directory as B?" it compares the names of files/directories ignoring differences in upper/lowercase (exactly what upper/lowercase differences count depends on the filesystem—it's non-obvious once you get beyond ASCII). A case-sensitive filesystem does not ignore those differences.

A case-preserving filesystem stores file names as given. A non-case-preserving filesystem does not; it'll typically convert all letters to uppercase before storing them (theoretically, it could use lowercase, or RaNsOm NoTe case, or whatever, but AFAIK all real-world ones used uppercase).

You can put those two attributes together in any combination. I'm not sure if you can find non-case-preserving case-sensitive filesystems, but you could certainly create one. All the other combinations exist or existed in real systems, though.

So a case-preserving, case-insensitive filesystem (the most common type of case-insensitive filesystem nowadays) will store and return file names in whatever capitalization you created them or last renamed them, but when comparing two file names (to check if one exists, to open one, to delete one, etc.) it'll ignore case differences.

When you use a case-insensitive filesystem on a Unix box, various utilities will do weird things because Unix traditionally uses case-sensitive filesystems—so they're not expecting `Document1` and `document1` to be the same file.

In the `pwd` case, what you're seeing is that it by default just outputs the path you actually used to get to the directory. So if you got there via `cd DirName`, it'll use `DirName` in the output. If you got there via `DiRnAmE`, you'll see `DiRnAmE` in the output. Bash does this by keeping track of how you got to your current directory in the `$PWD` environment variable. Mainly this is for symlinks (if you `cd` into a symlink, you'll see the symlink in your `pwd`, even though it's actually not part of the path to your current directory). But it also gives the somewhat weird behavior you observe on case-insensitive filesystems. I suspect that `pwd -P` will give you the directory name using the case stored on disk, but haven't tested.

Comment: I might have known you beat me to this one!  (upvoted)